# Powershell get variable value from remote host

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I know, that using -ArgumentList I can pass arguments to remote host:

```
$IISarrayValue = "$ENV:Cashier_NAME", "$ENV:Terminal_NAME"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $CompADName -Port 5985 -credential $credential -ArgumentList (,$IISarrayValue) -scriptblock {

Param ([string[]]$IISarrayValue)
echo $IISarrayValue
}
```

My question is - assume, that I gathered some information in variable on remote host. How can I get this variable back on my current host and use it outside of -scriptblock {}  ?

Comment: Just save the output of the command into a variable. e.g. `$returnedValue = Invoke-Command ...`
You are allready returning a value from the `Invoke-Command` trough your `echo` (not the best way).

Comment: @Paxz But what can I do, if i execute a bunch of commands inside -scriptblock {} ? Is there any alternatives?